# Hive query reading a list of constants from a text file?

Tags: hive

I want to extract data for a list of `userid` I am interested in. If the list is short, I can type the query directly:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE userid IN (100, 101, 102);
```

(this is an example, the query might be more complex). But the list of `userid` might be long and available as a text file:

```
100
101
102
```

How can I run the same query with Hive reading from `userids.txt` directly?

Answer (score 0):

One way is to put the data in another table and `INNER JOIN` to it, so that there has to be a match for the record to go through:

1. Create the table: `CREATE TABLE users (userid INT);`
2. Load the data file: `LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH 'userids.txt' INTO TABLE users;`
3. Filter through the inner join: `SELECT mytable.* FROM mytable INNER JOIN users ON mytable.userid = users.userid;`

Comment: You can use external table if you don't want the original file to be moved from it's current location.